# How database master key protect the certificate

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server system, If I need to create a symmetric key, I need to create a Database Master Key first, then a certificate, then the symmetric key, with the following code:

```
-- Create database master key
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ‘GoodLuckWithExam!’
-- Create certificate
CREATE CERTIFICATE Cert_BAN
WITH SUBJECT = ‘Bank Account Number’;
-- Create SMK
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY Key_BAN
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_BAN;
```

From here we could see that the SMK is protected by the certificate. However the certificate is NOT protected by the database master key, then my question is why we need the database master key at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate private key is encrypted using the database master key.
From [CREATE CERTIFICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='password'
Specifies the password used to encrypt the private key. Use this option only if you want to encrypt the certificate with a password. If this clause is omitted, the private key is encrypted using the database master key. Password must meet the Windows password policy requirements of the computer that is running the instance of SQL Server.